# unable to test google assistant action on web simulator (Error Cloud function deployment failed. Dismiss)

Tags: google-cloud-functions, webhooks, actions-on-google, google-developers-console, google-assistant

Hey Respected Community!

I started learning to create google actions.

so i created very basic google action. which invokes by 'hey google talk to Doctor Strange'
and after adding 1 more transition which displays suggestion. I saved it and trying to test it.
but continously getting error.

cloud function deployment failed.

[image]

i am continously trying to test it but getting error.

Can anyone help me what i am missing?
thanks in advance

Comment: The error message suggests that you are using an Inline Function. Are you? Can you click on the Develop -> Webhook page and include a screen shot of what you have there? And show us what the code says if so?

Comment: @Prisoner hey yess thankyou so much i got the clue.reason it was showing error was because i choosen the template so. it had inline function selected in webhook. which requires billing details to be added. so i just deleted all. and tried with blank project. and it worked.
i am so stupid.

Comment: Nothing stupid there - a bad error message that could do a better job explaining what was going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you surmise in your comments, using the Inline Editor for the webhook fulfillment requires you to have billing enabled for the cloud project it is attached to. (This is because it uses Cloud Functions for Firebase under the hood, and this requires billing to be enabled, even if you limit yourself to the free tier.)

You don't need to use the Inline Editor, or even Google Cloud Functions, for your webhook. All you need is a public HTTPS server that can accept and respond with JSON.